# Event Listeners-Jquery

Tags: jquery, event-listener

I hope everyone is having an amazing week so far.

I seem to be stumped on another exercise and I am hoping someone can help me.

The task is:

- Add the code to set the innerHTML of the home message to "Rocket Cars!" whenever the 'Change HTML' (id="change-html") button is clicked.

  ```
     <p id="HomeMessage" value="This is the home message">Change me with jQuery !</p>
     <button id="change-html">Change HTML</button>
  ```

The code I was given to complete is:

```
     $('#change-html').on('click', function () {
        //Your code here
     })
```

I have tried numerous ways to complete this but have not been successful. I have tried:

```
    $("#HomeMessage").html();
    $("#HomeMessage").html().click();
```

plus a bunch of other variations but am having no luck so far.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated :D

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Check the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/. The methods there are pretty much self-explanatory. You're on the right track using `html()`, you just need to provide an argument to the method call which is the HTML to set within the target element. You may also want to consider using `text()` instead if you're just setting a plain string value.

Comment: `.html()` *gets* you the current HTML of the element. To *set* it, pass an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $('#change-html').on('click', function () {
         $("#HomeMessage").html("Rocket Cars!");
})
```

or

```js
$('#change-html').on('click', function () {
         $("#HomeMessage").html($("#HomeMessage").html()+"Rocket Cars!");
})
```

With html jquery method you can do two things:

1. Set an html code for a specific element. (Pass the html code to the method as argument)
2. Get the html code of a specific element (Pass no argument to do that).

That's all!

I think it's easy.

Comment: Code-only answers are usually not very helpful for beginners. Please add an explanation.

Comment: @connexo answer updated.

Comment: Thank you!!! You helped me a lot Chris. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me today. :D You are awesome!!!